# SQL Server Substring buffer padding

Tags: sql, buffer, substring, padding

This is probably a simple question but I'm trying to create a new column in SQL server based off of 4 others.  The idea is to create a customer ID based off the first 5 characters of Zip, Last name, first name, and address.

My question is: how to I ensure that I get a spacing buffer if the name is too short?  For example, I have a guy with the first name of Tom.  How to I get it to return 'TOM  ' with the two spaces at the end?

**NOTE:**  I'm fully aware that creating a customer key based off something that can change like an address can cause problems. I've discussed that with the client and they said to do it anyway.

Comment: did any of these answers help you?

Answer (score 1):

Couple more ways

```
select STUFF('     ', 1, LEN(name), name)
select name + REPLICATE(' ', 5 - len(name))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
left (rtrim(@str) + '     ', 5)
```

That's five spaces ;-)